# On/Under Someone's Order(s)

Tags: prepositions, difference, usage

> 1. The captives were taken away ***on his order(s)***.
> 2. The captives were taken away ***under his order(s)***.

Dictionaries are vague about the difference between "***on*** *his order*" and "***under*** *his order*" and whether "*order*" should be singular or plural.

Comment: No difference as I see plenty of examples on authentic sites. Maybe, it's just a style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*On his order* (or *orders*) is an adverbial used to indicate either

1. the authority by which a specific action is carried out—this may use either the singular *order* or the plural.

   > Flags were lowered on the president's order.
2. the signal on which an action is to commence—here *order* is singular.

   > "Fire on my order ... Fire!"

*Under his orders* may be used in the same way as #1:

> The Colosseum was built under the orders of Emperor Vespasian.

But it also acts as

3. a figurative 'location'—the status of being obliged to follow the instructions of a particular person or institution.

   > The Fourth Division was placed under the orders of the general officer commanding the Second Army Corps.
   >   *Circe* now came under the orders of Commodore Sir Home Popham.